# Poison from bite

Tags: dnd-5e, poison

DM'ing my first 5e campaign. Had my players fighting Giant Spiders.  Monster manual states that the spiders bite does 1D8 +2 damage.  Character must also make a DC11 save on on failure takes 2D8 poison damage or saves for half.  My question is,  is he considered poisoned or do they just take poison damage?  If they save for half are they still poisoned as well? If he is that would mean even if the character saves he is still at disadvantage for all attacks. Is this correct? I saw a similar question but I did not get a clear answer.